# I worked on the React js application, and this problem appeared (TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

**strong text**    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Aux from '../../Aux/Aux';
import Modal from '../../components/UI/Modal/Modal'

```
const withErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent , axios) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
            error : null
        }
        componentDidMount (){
            axios.intetceptors.request.use(req => {
                this.setState({error:null});
                return req;
            })
            axios.intetceptors.response.use(res => res , error => {
                this.setState({error : error})
            })    }
            errorConfirm = () => {
                this.setState({error:null})
            }
        render (){
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Modal show ={this.state.error} modalClosed={this.errorConfirm}>
                    {this.state.error ? this.state.error.message : null}
                </Modal>
                <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
            </Aux>
        )}
    }
}

export default withErrorHandler;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have misspelled **`axios.intetceptors.request`** , it should be **`axios.interceptors.request`**.
Due to which it is resolving to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const withErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent , axios) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
            error : null
        }
        componentDidMount (){
            axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
                this.setState({error:null});
                return req;
            })
            axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res , error => {
                this.setState({error : error})
            })    }
            errorConfirm = () => {
                this.setState({error:null})
            }
        render (){
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Modal show ={this.state.error} modalClosed={this.errorConfirm}>
                    {this.state.error ? this.state.error.message : null}
                </Modal>
                <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
            </Aux>
        )}
    }
}

export default withErrorHandler;
```

You have a typo in axios.interceptors